# JUnit Tests not running in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

This is a snapshot of the eclipse editor. You can see the test and the JUnit tab. When I try to run the test, it says Terminated.

[image]

Anybody know what is going on here?

Comment: How do you run your test? I mean through the main method in your BasicInfoTest class or through right clicking in the eclipse package explorer?

Comment: I am right clicking and running as JUnit Test.

Comment: that looks like a test suite for me, can u run it as a Junit Test Suite rather than Junit Test case..

Answer (score 40):

In my case it was because Eclipse started using JUnit 5 as the test runner. I resolved the issue by going to Run Configuration and selecting the older test runner:
[image: test config]

Answer (score 7):

My case is different but I got the same junit error.
I had conflicts in junit dependences using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Having this, you have to use

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

instead of

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

Answer (score 5):

Manually define the run behavior: Right click -> Run As -> **Run Configurations**:

Then you could define the every details of the test case: test class, test methods, class path, junit version, JVM arguments, etc.

Comment: This solved my problem! Eclipse was trying to run a JUnit 4 with JUnit 5 by default.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if your problem is already solved.

I had a similar issue which got solved when I corrected the `Project` **->** `Properties` **->** `Java Compiler` **->** `JDK Compliance settings`.

I had a conflict between 1.5 and 1.6. When I reverted back to 1.5 (which was the current active JRE), my JUnits started working again.

Comment: I have seen the same, but when I set back 1.6 (and 1.8) it worked too. So revert back to 1.5 and then set it again to 1.6

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is that Eclipse's JUnit runner is confused by the presence of the `main` method and is running that rather than the test methods.

Try commenting out the `main` method.  It shouldn't be there at all, IMO.

(By the way, the main method doesn't look right to me.  I'd have thought it would instantiate a `TestSuite` with the unit test classes as parameters, but you seem to be giving it the class under test.  That won't have any "test" methods, which would explain why no tests are being run ...)

Answer (score 2):

Like already mentioned, remove the main method, might helpt. Any particular reason for extend from TestCase that is Juni3 if I remember correctly? Did you try Junit 4 by using @Test annotation

for instance:

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
     //you stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when first added the junit jar file to the build path. 
Make sure youre adding the junit.jar file to the Java Build Path -> Classpath section, rather than modulepath section

Comment: Thanks! I Added it to my Module Path and had no idea what was going on

Answer (score 2):

I was using wrong @Test, try importing @Test from `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case was that I had done a refactoring and the .classpath was not updated and the console was showing an error about invalid class. After updating the classpath file, everything started to work again.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but in my case the I had to update my project configuration Maven->update Project configuration before Junit finally started responding

Answer (score 0):

When I saw no tests being run I opened the console and saw the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: junit/framework/Test (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadTestLoaderClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:328)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createRawTestLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:318)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:313)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.defaultInit(RemoteTestRunner.java:291)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.init(RemoteTestRunner.java:212)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

After further investigation I realized that the junit framework I was using was built against a 1.6 jre and I was building my unit tests against a 1.3 jre. When I built my unit tests against 1.6 my tests ran.  Alternatively, I suppose I could have built (or found) junit against 1.3 and I could have been in good shape. I went the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when I had two jars of junit on the classpath. One jar was hidden inside selenium server standalone. I fixed the issue by removing the other jar from the classpath and letting the runtime use the junit jar in the selenium server standalone. I couldn't find any messages in the console about a class conflict or java version warning.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using an inner class which was not being identified as  eligible for tests. The fix was to make that class a static inner class like this:

```
public class MyClass { //... class I wanted to test
}
```

This inner class (i.e. in the same file) is used for testing MyClass - but eclipse does not found it ... unless it is static.

```
public static class MyClassTest  { // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have another process blocking execution. In my case, building workspace was sleeping, blocking all junit execution.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your bottom area 'Progress' tab to see if there are any missing project dependencies when trying to run your JUnit test.  That was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with my test cases too until I realized am not using the right dependencies. Please try checking the test dependencies you're using. Moreso, you cannot add mockito dependency to test a J unit case. That's a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with my VPN. I have to turn off my VPN whenever I use Debug. But apparently, it also needs to be turned off when running JUnit tests, whether in 'Run' or 'Debug' mode.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound silly, but have you checked that Eclipse isn't running any other process in the background?
In my case, the tests were waiting for another process to complete.
You can check this in the Progress tab in the Java EE view.
[image: Progress tab in Eclipse]

I hope it helps!